# SplitView elements both in horizontally and vertically in qml

Tags: layout, qml, splitview

I am having below elements in QML
A and B in a Rowlayout1
C and D in Rowlayout2

A and B is already Splitted horizontally using SplitView
C and D is already Splitted horizontally using SplitView

No I need to Split A and C as VERTICAL and
B and D as VERTICAL
IS that POSSIBLE?

```
ColumnLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent 
    spacing: 20
    
    SplitView{                              //THis is not working properly, I need to split VERICALLY the layouts
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true 
        orientation: Qt.Vertical
    

        RowLayout {
            spacing:20
            Layout.preferredHeight: 500 
     
             SplitView {
                Layout.fillWidth: true 
                Layout.fillHeight: true 
                orientation: Qt.Horizontal
                    Rectangle {
                        SplitView.preferredWidth: 200
                        SplitView.fillHeight: true
                        color: "lightblue"
                        Text {
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            text: "View A"
                        }
                    }
                    Rectangle {
                        SplitView.fillWidth: true
                        SplitView.fillHeight: true
                        color: "lightgreen"
                        Text {
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            text: "View B"
                        }
                    }
               }
               
            }
            
            RowLayout {
            spacing:20
            Layout.preferredHeight: 500
     
             SplitView {
                Layout.fillWidth: true 
                Layout.fillHeight: true 
                orientation: Qt.Horizontal
                    Rectangle {
                        SplitView.preferredWidth: 200
                        SplitView.fillHeight: true
                        color: "lightblue"
                        Text {
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            text: "View C"
                        }
                    }
                    Rectangle {
                        SplitView.fillWidth: true
                        SplitView.fillHeight: true
                        color: "lightgreen"
                        Text {
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            text: "View D"
                        }
                    }
               }
               
            }
        }
    }
```

I am having below elements in QML
A and B in a Rowlayout1
C and D in Rowlayout2

A and B is already Splitted horizontally using SplitView
C and D is already Splitted horizontally using SplitView

No I need to Split A and C as VERTICAL and
B and D as VERTICAL
IS that POSSIBLE?

Comment: This can't be realised with SplitViews. You have to implement your your 2-way splitter, if you want to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a row and column headers and just put the `SplitView` in the headers. In the following diagram, we place one `SplitView` for `C1` and `C2` and another `SplitView` for `R1` and `R2`.

| Corner | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | A | B |
| R2 | C | D |

Here's an example QML:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    title: "Dual SplitViews"
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Title {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 60
                Layout.preferredHeight: 60
                text: "Corner"
            }
            SplitView {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 60
                TitleC1 { id: titleC1 }
                TitleC2 { id: titleC2 }
            }
        }
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            SplitView {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 60
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                orientation: Qt.Vertical
                TitleR1 { id: titleR1 }
                TitleR2 { id: titleR2 }
            }
            Item {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Cell {
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    width: titleC1.width
                    height: titleR1.height
                    text: "A"
                    backgroundColor: "lightblue"
                }
                Cell {
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    width: titleC2.width
                    height: titleR1.height
                    text: "B"
                    backgroundColor: "lightgreen"
                }
                Cell {
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    width: titleC1.width
                    height: titleR2.height
                    text: "C"
                    backgroundColor: "lightblue"
                }
                Cell {
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    width: titleC2.width
                    height: titleR2.height
                    text: "D"
                    backgroundColor: "lightgreen"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Title.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Label {
    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
    background: Rectangle { color: "#eee" }
}

// TitleC1.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Title {
    SplitView.preferredWidth: 200
    text: "C1"
}

// TitleC2.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Title {
    text: "C2"
}

// TitleR1.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Title {
    SplitView.preferredHeight: 200
    text: "R1"
}

// TitleR2.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Title {
    text: "R2"
}

// Cell.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Label {
    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
    property color backgroundColor: "lightblue"
    background: Rectangle {
        color: backgroundColor
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)